# Parse one string to another

Tags: string

```
string A = "myString";

string B;
```

Is there a way to initiate B according to the data of A, so that value B changes with A.

```
B = capture change of A?
```

Edit: My initial post was not complete and misleading, I found the answer now. Still my question is a duplicate of [observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx)

Comment: Based on what you've provided, substring() would do what you're after. Are you thinking of something a bit more complex?

Comment: strange, guys are answering such type of questions,

Comment: First two elements = first two characters, or first of two elements as in split by uppercase characters

Answer (score 7):

Try this

> B = A.Substring(0,2);

It initates `B` with substring of `A` from index 0 and lenght of 2

Answer (score 1):

Sure, using [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
B = A.Substring(0,2);  //"my"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following example

```
string A = "myString";
string B;

if (A.StartsWith("my"))
{
    B = A.Substring(0, 2);//first two elements of A
}
```

Check out this [Substring method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)